# How to make a image transparent

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a sample code for welcome page in inno setup that will fill the background with a image.
Here is the code I used :

```
[Files]
Source: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe; DestDir: {app}
Source: F:\image.bmp; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
    ImageFile: String;
    Image: TBitmapImage;
begin
    ImageFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\image.bmp');
    ExtractTemporaryFile('image.bmp');
    Image := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
    with Image do
    begin
        Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ImageFile);
        Parent := WizardForm.WelcomePage;
        Autosize := True
        ReplaceColor := $00FF00FF;                        // Replace magenta...
        ReplaceWithColor := WizardForm.WelcomePage.Color; // ...with the background color of the page
    end;
end;
```

**This code make the installer like the image below :**

[image]

**Now my question is is there any way to make that text transparent so user can see the full image.**
I hope you all understand what I am trying to say.
Thanks.

Comment: @TLama Is it possible use the image in all the pages  like wpinstalling, wp selecttask etc.Thanks

Comment: It is, but for other pages is the situation more complicated. It's quite a lot of coding. I would rather suggest looking for some 3rd party plugins.

Comment: @Tlama what  3rd party plugins? can you tell a name of  '3rd party plugins'. Thanks

Comment: For example [Graphical Installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com/).

Comment: @TLama but Graphical Installer is paid application.

Comment: I know. But I can't remember any other. I know there were some suspicious blackboxed libraries from Russia and a few plugins for skinning, but they were not fully graphical. There was even question about it on Stack Overflow. So sorry, but I'm out help here.